# iOS Clear UIView and redraw drawRect:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, drawrect

I want my custom view to clear everything (subviews, sublayers, drawings, etc.) in it and call `drawRect:` again when pressing a button, so it will be like getting a clean slate and painting on it again.

Right now, I've tried using `setNeedsDisplay` and it just draws over the whole thing without cleaning the previous work.

A snippet of code in my drawRect:

```
if (_displayYAxisAverageLine) {
    // Check if y axis data are numbers
    for (id yValue in yAxisValues) {
        if (![yValue isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
            return;
        }
    }

    NSNumber *average = [yAxisValues valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.self"];

    CGFloat scale = [self scaleForYValue:average];
    CGFloat avgLineY = roundf(graphHeight * scale)+_graphInset;

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, avgLineY)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(contentWidth, avgLineY)];

    CAShapeLayer *avgLine = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    avgLine.path = path.CGPath;
    avgLine.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    avgLine.strokeColor = _borderColor.CGColor;
    avgLine.lineWidth = 1.f;
    avgLine.lineDashPattern = @[@2, @2];

    [self.contentView.layer addSublayer:avgLine];
}
```

Comment: Subviews are unrelated to drawRect:. Can you show some specifics about what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have a custom chart, and according to the BOOL value of certain properties I add some labels and CAShapeLayers in drawRect:.

Comment: You shouldn't — drawRect is not meant for adding sublayers. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/SettingUpLayerObjects/SettingUpLayerObjects.html / https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html

Comment: Then where is a good place to do it?

Comment: You can do it whenever your properties change, or perhaps layoutSubviews... lots of options

Comment: The code doesn't work anywhere else. I'm doing everything the way people draw in drawRect: except I'm applying UIBezierPaths to CAShapeLayers and adding those layers instead of using CGContext. My custom view has a scroll view subview that sets its width according to the interItemSpacing property and many other drawings that are dependent on how the properties are set. I think everything should be laid out last minute, but I don't know how view controllers make views work. And I'm not sure if drawing them each time the property is set is efficient or recommended.